# My custom arraylist is not sorting properly in android Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-android-extensions

`val sortedList =   allNovelList.sortedWith(compareBy { (it as Novel).no })`
   And
`allNovelList.sortBy { (it as Novel).no }`

I have a list of custom object, in which there are integer 'no' is added like id or primary key.
From 0 to 9 sorting is working very fine but after 9 , 10 is below to 1.

I am working in Kotlin for Android for first time. I have looked all around the web but I could not get the proper code.

Both lines are giving same sorting.
What I want,
1,2,3,....,9,10,11,12....,
And What I get after sorting.
1,10,11,2,3,4,5,6...,9

It is sorting like alphabetically.

Comment: Are you sure that `no` is integer?

Comment: no, i am saving it in object as string.

Comment: @forpas ,But I got your point what you want to say.
let me check it.
Thanks for your pointing out the reason.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you mentioned in your comment, `no` is a String, so it sorts it with string sort rules in mind.

You should try this:

```
val sortedList = allNovelList.sortBy { (it as Novel).no.toInt() }
```

Make sure that `no` is an Integer.

Comment: @Muhammad Rehan Accept and upvote an answer if it solves your problem

Comment: Yeah, I would love to do, But stackoverflow is not allowing me to upvote because my reputation is less than 15.
So, That's why.